# How to fix OutOfMemoryError exception while loading large size of data from web service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory, out-of-memory

I am getting OutOfMemoryError when downloading images from network.I am trying to display downloaded images to ImageView in Listview inside AsyncTask implementation.

Following is the log of the error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 27211152 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
```

Comment: Yes, everything looks pretty clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are attempting to retrieve too big of a response through QuickBlox.

Comment: Voting to close as "not a question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much we can tell you about this without more information than just the stacktrace for your exception. You should set breakpoints in your code and find out where the error is occurring. Then give us more information based on what the problem is. If you don't know how to do this let me know and I'll try to help walk you through it.

An out of memory error just means that the device or VM that your code is running on ran out of memory to allocate while it still had new tasks to complete. This can be caused by way too many things for us to just know what to do without any additional info.

Comment: I am trying to load **chat message history** with large number of images, video, text and trying to display in custom list view. But this thing sometime works and sometime not.

Comment: Out of memory errors are rarely consistent. It largely depends on how big the files you're working with, and how many of them you're trying to hold in  memory at once. If you're working with bitmaps, make sure you use Bitmap.recycle() to free memory. Otherwise you may need to find a way to release unused memory specific to what objects you're using.

It sounds like your problem is that your code is trying to do too many things at once, and needs to be optimized.

Comment: Thank you all for your nobel answers

Answer (score 0):

Solved error by using 3rd party image loading libraries like:
 - Picasso 
 - Universal Image Loader
 - Glide